# Celery task state not updated with ignore_result set to True, though update_state() called

Tags: python, celery

I am not sure if there is something that I misunderstand regarding Celery's result backend settings, but this is the problem I am facing: I have a bunch of tasks that I am not interested in their result, but I do want to check on their state from time to time.
Hence I have set:

```
ignore_result = True
```

Despite this setting, it seems that if I have the result backend configured to use AMQP, the result queues are still being created - one per task - why?
So I tried to make sure I won't have too many (result) queues at the same time (which would affect the performance of RabbitMQ) by setting:

```
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 60
```

The weird thing is that if I don't manage to check:

```
AsyncResult(task_id).state
```

within the first 60s after a task has finished, then the state of the task will be forever PENDING, even though for some tasks I manually call

```
update_state(state='SUCCESS')
```

in the task. What is even more weird is that whenever I try to get the task state, despite the fact that all the states are PENDING (though they should be one of the FINISHED_STATES), the result queues reappear in the list of queues, but the task state never changes - I list all the queues using rabbitmqadmin before checking on the task state and after.

Can anybody explain me what am I doing wrong or what is going on?
Why is the state of a task depending on the result expiry time, if I ignore the result entirely?

What settings should I use if I want to ignore the result of the tasks, but still be able to check on the task's state?

p.s. I am using Celery 3.0.23 now, but the behaviour was the same with 3.0.13.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316133/celery-task-state-depends-on-celery-task-result-expires and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876863/task-state-and-django-celery/13241895#13241895.